# Installed Cyrus / tls_sessions.db not created / process not running

Tags: imap, cyrus

I installed cyrus-imapd and cyrus-admin via `apt-get install`. When I try to start the service with `/etc/init.d/cyrus-imapd start`, I got `[ ok ] Starting cyrus-imapd (via systemctl): cyrus-imapd.service.` as the response but there is no process running. In `/var/log/mail.err` I got the following message:

```
cyrus/tls_prune[8761]: DBERROR: opening /var/lib/cyrus/tls_sessions.db: cyrusdb error
cyrus/master[8721]: process type:START name:tlsprune path:/usr/sbin/cyrus age:0.000s pid:8761 exited, status 1
cyrus/master[8721]: can't run startup
```

I don't know what went wrong. The file `/var/lib/cyrus/tls_sessions.db` doesn't exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect that @Francesc Guasch's answer is correct. So why not accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create this file and give it permissions for the cyrus user:

```
# touch /var/lib/cyrus/tls_sessions.db
# chown cyrus:mail tls_sessions.db
```

Check the other files in /var/lib/cyrus so the owner and group are the same as in the new file. Mine are *cyrus,mail* and I guess yours will be the same.

Then restart the service and it should work.

Hope it helps.